# What motherboard supports new i5 integrated graphics?

Tags: cpu, integrated-graphics

The i5 sandy bridge processer (recall aside) has built in Intel HD Graphics 2000/3000 graphics.  I simply would like to know what motherboard supports this (e.g. has video ports to utilize the cpu integrated graphics)?  I tried to search for this but am unsure what keywords to use.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a chipset dependency. The high-end boards (with P67 chipset) don't support the built-in graphics, as users will presumably buy a separate graphic card with them. The mainboards with the H67 chipset support the built-in graphics. So if you shop at a seller who lets you filter for chipset, you can find it easily.

I think that it is theoretically possible for somebody to build a board with the H67 which doesn't support the integrated graphics, but I haven't heard of it happening. However, there will be a lot of H67 mainboards coming to the market in the next months, so make sure to check that the board you have chosen has a video output too. Both together - H67 chipset and the presence of a video port - should be enough.

An example of a H67 mainboard would be the MSI H67MA-E45 (a MicroATX board). It supports the Sandy Bridge graphics and offers HDMI, DVI or VGA output.

And on a side note: if you are in the market for a new mainboard, make sure it has all the legacy slots you need. Lots of manufacturers start phasing out PCI this generation.

Answer (score 0):

for sandy bridge you can either get a P67 or a H67 chipset motherboard. The H67 chipset has support for the cpu's HD graphics (the same logic goes with the 1st generation P55/H55)